# subclass constructor using super's constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Initially this was defined

```
class Mammal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def say(self):
        return("What does the " + self.name + " says")
```

but now we want to create subclasses of Mammals, whose constructor will call the Mammal's constructor with the correct name.

```
  class Dog(Mammal):
        def __init__(self):
            Dog.self
```

This is my code. It says `type object 'Dog' has no attribute 'self'` what's the problem?

when `print(Dog().get_name())` I should get Dog.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Python 2.x, you should write

```
super(Dog, self).__init__('name')
```

or, for Python 3:

```
super().__init__('name')
```

instead of

```
Dog.self
```

See [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods) for detail.

If you want `Dog().get_name()` to return 'Dog', you should call

```
super(Dog, self).__init__('Dog')
```

Answer (score 3):

You should write like this:

```
class Dog(Mammal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('dog name')
```